# How to search efficiently for a package using Msys2 pacman?

Tags: python, msys2, pacman-package-manager

When I search for a Package like this

```
pacman -Qs python
local/python2 2.7.15-2
    A high-level scripting language
local/scons 3.0.1-1 (base-devel)
    Extensible Python-based build utility
```

2 packages are listed and no python-3 ackage is found

but if I try to install any python like this

```
pacman -S python

resolving dependencies…
looking for conflicts …

Packages (2) mpdecimal-2.4.2-2  python-3.6.6-1
```

a python-3 package does appear !

What is the effective way to query packages using pacman ?

Comment: don't use the pacman tag: it's the _game_... Yes, I know...

Comment: surprising in the stack overflow context, thanks for the update anyway

Comment: no, read the tag description of "pacman". I've edited to put the proper tag in your question. I've already asked that the 'pacman' tag to be deleted but it was declined...

Answer (score 4):

ok as stated [here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/pacman#Querying_package_databases) 
To search for already installed packages:

```
$ pacman -Qs string1 string2 ...
```

Pacman can search for packages in the database, searching both in packages' names and descriptions:

```
$ pacman -Ss string1 string2 ...
```

Comment: what do u mean by `string1 string2`? this way is used for "and"-ing strings, so, in effect it's all just one string. i wanted to search for "or" like search for string1 or string2 (as in searching for multiple packages at once) but couldn't find a way.

Comment: @user8395964 ok but according to the link "here" (https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/pacman#Querying_package_databases) I though it would be an or. I didn't practice with pamcan since a long time